# Align comments on multiple lines of R code

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm wondering if there is a way to write code in absolute positions in a Notebook R of RSTudio. For example I'd like to shift the cursor in an absolute position so that I can write the code and the comments in an orderly fashion.

```
media          # stampo media
n*p            # calcolo senza salvare e stampo media teorica

varianza       # stampo varianza
n*p*(1-p)      # calcolo senza salvare e stampo varianza teorica
```

Comment: Not sure if it's worth it for you, but you might dig into the source code of the styler package. From the issues, it looks like this is something they're working on but haven't implemented: https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/518

Comment: Hello @camille thank you for the suggestion; it seems that they want to implement another kind of layout for the comments

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted the {AlignAssign} RStudio add-in package, to also align comments. If you install the add-in from GitHub: https://github.com/nrennie/AlignAssign

```r
remotes::install_github("nrennie/AlignAssign")
```

Then select the lines in your R script that you want to align the comments for, click "Addins" and select "Align Comment", this should align all the comments after you've written them.

The original repository that aligns `<-` or `=` is here, for interest: https://github.com/seasmith/AlignAssign

Comment: I had to add `force = T` : `remotes::install_github("nrennie/AlignAssign", force = T)`