# What RStudio add-in can I use to align R code?

Tags: r, alignment, rstudio

I remember that there is an add-in to achieve the alignment of text

```r
var <- 1
variable <- 2
```

to

```r
var      <- 1
variable <- 2
```

Comment: Google says: https://statsandr.com/blog/rstudio-addins-or-how-to-make-your-coding-life-easier/#styler

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/15703553/680068

Comment: I had another package in mind than `styler`, and I'm not sure that it does the job

Comment: There is also formatR: https://yihui.org/formatr/

Comment: The add-in I was looking for is [AlignAssign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75779472/8806649)

Comment: Great, I added the link.